# Parse Integer error

Tags: java, string, parseint

For some reason I cant get a string number value to convert to an integer the error I get is
run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "6327818260"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:495)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at MyDirectory.getsize(MyDirectory.java:18)
    at a19010.main(a19010.java:79)
```

Java Result: 1

If my input string is "6327818260" why can't it become an integer? my code is

```
public String getsize()
{
  int intSize = Integer.parseInt(mySize);
  int count = 0;
  String dataType = "";
  while (intSize > 1000)
  {   
   intSize = intSize / 1000;
   count++;
  } 
  switch (count)
  {
    case 0:
    dataType = "Bytes";
    break;
    case 1:
    dataType = "KB";
    break;
    case 2:
    dataType = "MB";
    break;
    case 3:
    dataType = "GB";
    break;
    case 4:
    dataType = "KB";
    break;    
  }   
    return intSize + dataType ;
}
```

mySize is taken from part of a string gotten from a text file here

```
 public class MyDirectory 
{
  String myName = "" ;
  String myNum = "";
  String mySize = "";
    public MyDirectory(String line)

  {
    line = line.trim();  
    String[] lineParts = line.split(" ");
     mySize = lineParts[0];
     myNum = lineParts[1];
     myName = lineParts[3];
  }
```

The line im splitting looks like 
   6327818260   6486  SUB-TOTAL: E:\WIS26\LCORRES

Comment: What is the maximum value of an Integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The largest possible integer is 
`2147483647`
which is a good deal less than the value you're trying to parse:
`6327818260`

You will need to use a long or a BigInteger/BigDecimal to hold that value.

For BigInteger/BigDecimal Strings representing base 10 integers can be parsed by the constructors that take a string argument.

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal("6327818260");
```

Comment: Is there a method to turn a string into a big decimal? Im have trouble  initializing the big decimal from the mySize string

Comment: The constructor that takes a String understands decimal integers.

Comment: That's what I thought I must be doing something incorrectly my constructor looks like  BigDecimal size = BigDecimal(mySize);

Comment: That fixed it of corse. I guess I forgot for some reason

Answer (score 2):

```
6327818260 is greater than the Integer.MAX_VALUE `2147483647`
```

You can try to parse the string to `Long`

Comment: This lets my code compile but It doesn't work for the division since it get rid of the decimal

Comment: if it is decimal, try BigDecimal. you can `BigDecimal dc = new BigDecimal(str);`

Answer (score 0):

If it's a 32-bit integer you're looking to pack that into, it's too big.